# Sending arguments to std::thread object

Tags: c++, multithreading, implicit-conversion

Suppose we got this code:

```
void err(std::string const& field){
    for(int i=0; i<field.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << field[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void test() {
    char field[]= "abcdef";
    std::thread t1(err, field); ///problem
    t1.detach();
}

int main(){
    test();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return 0;
}
```

This program won't execute properly and I really want to know what is the reason behind it. As far as I'm concered, std::thread objects copies the arguments we sent them. Here's what I think happened:

`field` gets converted to `char*` (temporary object) and `std::thread` object copies that `char*` object. Meanwhile we have detached our thread and the function finishes. The function deletes its local variables (so `char field[]` no longer exists) and so our `char*` iniside our `std::thread` object holds invalid address therefore we cannot convert that `char*` into temporary `std::string` in order to bind `const std::string` reference to it.

Am I right ? What am I missing ? Also, does the same explanation applies if the function's signature was `void err(std::string const field)` (no reference now) ?

By the way, I know the solution to this would be `std::thread t1(err, std::string(field));`.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but detaching threads is a bad habit to get into. There are a few situations where detaching is appropriate, but this is not one of them.

Comment: You are right, and "no reference now" will still be undefined behavior.